# async await question in Firebase Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to get the document and the subcollection data at once in firestore.
And I used the async and await to deal with the forEach loop.
It still has some problem. The console.log `4` always executes first.

But what I expect the should be 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4.
Could anyone help me how to redesign my code?

```
let data = {};

toolboxesRef.get()
.then(async snapshot => {
  let toolboxes = [];
  // get toolbox
  await snapshot.forEach(async doc => {
    let toolbox = {};
    await toolboxesRef.doc(doc.id).collection('tags').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      let tags = []
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        tags.push(doc.id);
        console.log(1)
      })
      toolbox.tags = tags;
      toolbox.id = doc.id;
      toolbox.data = doc.data(); 
      console.log(2)
    })
    console.log(3)
    toolboxes.push(toolbox)
  })
  console.log(4);
  data.toolboxes = toolboxes
  return data;
})
```

Comment: try `async.each()` from async library. check out this https://www.npmjs.com/package/async.

Answer (score 1):

```js
export const asyncForEach = async (dataSnapshot, callback) => {
    const toWait = [];
    dataSnapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        toWait.push(childFunction((childSnapshot)));
    });
    await Promise.all(toWait);
};
```

Hey i updated the code because it seems that Firebase integrate it's own foreach function. Then in order to resolve i decided to call every function and store the promise that it return into an array then i use `Promise.all` to resolve an array of async function

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've try use for...of to iterate the snapshot. But it shows error messages that the snapshot is not iterable. Do you have any idea? Thank you.

Comment: I check the type of snapshot. It's object.

Answer (score -1):

You are using async operations inside `forEach` which doesn't work as you expect thm. You need to either use `for..of` or `Promise.all`. Try this version

```
const snapshot = await toolboxesRef.get();
const toolboxes = [];
for(const doc of snapshot) {
  const toolbox = {};
  const snapshot1 = await toolboxesRef.doc(doc.id).collection("tags").get();
  const tags = [];
  snapshot1.forEach(doc => {
    tags.push(doc.id);
    console.log(1);
  });
  toolbox.tags = tags;
  toolbox.id = doc.id;
  toolbox.data = doc.data();
  console.log(2);
  console.log(3);
  toolboxes.push(toolbox);
}
console.log(4);
data.toolboxes = toolboxes;
return data;
```

You might need to tweak few things here and there but you will get an idea.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've try use `for...of` to iterate the snapshot. But it shows error messages that the snapshot is not iterable. Do you have any idea? Thank you.

Comment: I check the type of snapshot. It's object.

Comment: @charlestseng how were iterating in your case? You used `forEach`

Comment: Hmm it's weird. I found someone who use get() in Firebase also comment that it  return the promise(promise). 

Do you know any other way to solve this problem? 
Should I try to convert the snapshot to array?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149138/use-async-foreach-loop-while-fetching-data-from-firestore#comment93189181_53149138

Comment: I found an answer on this site. I should use `snapshot.docs` not only `snapshot`.
https://medium.com/@vladfr/use-cloud-firestore-with-async-bce875af0183